# Java Percentage and Heading

Tags: java

Hi I am currently working on a game in Java, that tests the users ability to work better with our without music for analyzing. I am using write file and created a .txt file to save the results. I was unsure how do i create headings for the saved results such as First name: Second Name. I am also a little lost as to calculate a percentage from the results. The results are stored in variables, Score and Score 2 i simply would like to display the percentage of the results. Thank you.

```
if(Globals.score2 > Globals.score) {
    //Better with music
    MessageBox.infoBox("You scored " + Globals.score + " without music & " + Globals.score2 + " with music!\n" + "You seemed to concentrate better while music was playing!" , "Score");
} else if (Globals.score2 < Globals.score) {
    //Better Without Music
    MessageBox.infoBox("You scored " + Globals.score + " without music & " + Globals.score2 + " with music!\n" + "You seemed to concentrate better without any music playing!" , "Score");
} else {
    //Equal Reults
    MessageBox.infoBox("You scored " + Globals.score +  " without music & " + Globals.score2 + " with music!\n" + "Your concentration stayed the same through each play through!" , "Score");
}  
// JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your score for game one was" + "" + Globals.score2 );
new FinalScore().setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);

toolkit.beep();
timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
//System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
```

//CODE FOR WRITING TO FILE

```
public class WriteFile {
    public static void SaveGame() throws IOException {
        String content = (Globals.IDUser + ", " + Globals.firstName + ", " + Globals.lastName + ", " + Globals.userAge + ", " + Globals.eThnic + ", " + Globals.maleOrFem  + ", " + " In the first game you scored, " + Globals.score + ", " + " In the second game you scored." + Globals.score2);
        File file = new File("ResultsSaves.txt");

        // if file exists, then overwrite current saved file with new
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close(); 

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your details have been saved!");   

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is the code that writes to the file? Or is your question how you can write to a file in Java, in which case there are probably already a lot of answers, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file

Comment: @KuluLimpa Hi, i have added the code that I used to extract to a text file above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you ask two things:

#### How to calculate the percentage of the score?

You don't really say a percentage of what, but I assume you want to calculate the fraction of `score` from `score + score2` (and analogous for `score2`).

I'm going to assume that `Globals.score` and `Globals.score2` are both of type `double`. Therefore, the percentage would be computed as

```
double scorePercentage = 100 * Globals.score / (Globals.score + Globals.score2)
```

#### How to print a heading 'row' before saving the game results?

Well... really just the same as you save your game results. It's even easyier as the heading is statically known.

However, if I am not mistaken, creating a separate `BufferedWriter` for printing the heading and the results would not append to the file but overwrite the previous output. My suggestion is to instantiate the `BufferedWriter` as part of `WriteFile`'s initialization. The `WriteFile` class could look something like this:

```
public final class WriteFile {

    private WriteFile(){/* This is a class with only static methods - make the constructor private to prohibit instantiation */}

    public static final String heading = "UserID, First Name, Last Name, Age, Ethnic, Gender, Score Game 1, Score Game 2";

    private static BufferedWriter bufferedFileWriter = null;

    static {
        File file = new File("ResultsSaves.txt");

        // if file exists, then overwrite current saved file with new
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bufferedFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    }

    private static String getGameResult() {
        return Globals.IDUser + ", " + Globals.firstName + ", " + Globals.lastName + ", " + Globals.userAge + ", " + Globals.eThnic + ", " + Globals.maleOrFem  + ", " + " In the first game you scored, " + Globals.score + ", " + " In the second game you scored." + Globals.score2; 
    }

    /** Not really needed, but there to stay true to the original design */
    public static void printHeading() throws IOException {
        save(heading); 
    }

    /** Not really needed, but there to stay true to the original design */
    public static void saveGame() throws IOException {
        save(getGameResult()); 
    }

    public static void save(String content) throws IOException {

        bufferedFileWriter.write(content);
        bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
        // flush to get the contents stored to file
        bufferedFileWriter.flush();  

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your details have been saved!");   

        }
    }

    /** Don't close the writer before all desired content is written. */
    public static void close() throws IOException {
        bufferedFileWriter.close(); 
    }
}
```

---

**Friendly advice**: Be careful when using global variables. They can become a hell of a debugging nightmare. You should prefer passing them as parameters to your methods.